# How to set the background color of a specific item in listview by position?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I want to set the background color of a specific item in the listview.

My listview is generated by ArrayAdapter using a ArrayList.

I have a specific item in the listview that I plan to change the background color.

I know the item's position in the list.

This is my code for generating the listview.

```
respondMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.respondMessageListView);
respondMessageListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, autoRespondMessages.getMessages()));
```

Thank you!

[edit]

According to [this post](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh/issues/26), using setSelection makes no effect if is used in onCreate(), the work around is "remove the method `onAttachedToWindow` in `PullToRefreshListView`". I am not quite understanding the solution. May I ask how should I accomplish this? I am a subclass of `Activity`, so I cannot subclass any other class anymore.

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055277/set-a-background-color-to-a-selected-listview-item-in-android

Comment: I tried, it gives me nullpointerexception on myList.getSelectedView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(Color.RED));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to subclass `ArrayAdapter` and override the [getView(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method. For simplicity's sake you could just call through to the base class implementation and set the background color for the returned `View`.

Edit:
The following example colors the items' backgrounds alternating black and white.

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    ...

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        v.setBackgroundColor(position % 2 == 0 : 0xff000000, 0xffffffff);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the same thing. Subclassing ArrayAdapter allows you to override the necessary method. Subclassing Activity doesn't get you anything. Here.

Comment: Um.. I mean I can only subclass one class... so if I subclassed Activity, I cannot subclass ArrayAdapter anymore

Comment: You can subclass as many classes as you want. I think you're confusing this with multiple inheritance.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't understand. Java only accept one class after keyword extends... How can I subclass both Activity and ArrayAdapter?

Comment: Instead of saying `respondMessageListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(...))` you would say `respondMessageListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(...))`. In another file called MyAdapter.java you would subclass ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

This code is for the when you select the listitem.

Try this code...

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int pos, long mylng) {

             if( pos == 1) {
                   // to change the listview background
                   listview.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color_id));

                   // to change the selected item background color
                   myView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color_id));
             }
            }
          });
```

Good luck.